# Facebook sharing debugger does not display the page title

Tags: seo, facebook, meta-tags, facebook-graph

I am working on a page that has music content and is partially rendered on the server (`<head>` and its contents as well as the basic html structure are rendered server side, the rest of the page is rendered on the client)

The related meta tags, that *are* included in the server render are the following:

```
<title>TRACK_NAME</title>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP_ID">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="SITE_NAME">
<meta property="og:title" content="TRACK_NAME">
<meta property="og:type" content="music.song">
```

The problem is that on the facebook sharing debugger (as well as in an actual Messenger message) the title does not appear.

I either get "No Title" or a random string instead of a title.

What is even stranger is that in the "Open Graph Object Debugger" section of the debugger, the `og:title` information, in the "Based on the raw tags, we constructed the following Open Graph properties" table, is in fact correct.

I have re-scraped the page countless times, I even gave it one day's worth of time, in case some internal cache was incorrect, but I still have this issue.

Based on the information I have shared here, does it sound like a facebook bug or an error on my part?